# Prepare package with Cython extension to publish on PyPI

Tags: python, package, python-import, packaging, setup.py

I'm going to create C library and I would like to create Python wrapper using Cython.

Right now I have `mylib.a` file compiled and bundled (C files) and I want to wrap methods from my library in Cython.

I successfully created `.pyx` and `.pxd` files and I can build an extension using `python setup.py build_ext` command. My problem appears when I try to publish it on PyPI. If I run my `setup.py`, create a wheel and publish it I can download it from PyPI - but I can't run `import mylib`.

I read a lot online tutorials for this. Few of them shown that theirs C code compiled on user side. My codebase will be constructed from many files and I would prefer to supply already build C code as `.a` file.

My file structure (only important files):

```
/ lib
    - mylib.a
    - *.h files (for mylib.a)
- setup.py
/ mylib
    - mylib.pyx
    - cmylib.pxd
    - __init__.py
```

My `__init__.py` file (after importing package downloaded from PyPI it throws errors here):

```
from . import mylib
```

My `setup.py` (only important parameters - in my opinion):

```
setup(name='mylib'
      packages=['mylib'],
      ext_modules = [Extension(
          name="mylib", 
          sources=["mylib/mylib.bycython.c"], 
          include_dirs = [numpy.get_include(), "lib/"],
          extra_objects=["lib/mylib.a"])],
        "build_ext": build_ext
      }
)
```

(I build `mylib.bycython.c` from `mylib.pyx` using `cython` command before `python setup.py build_ext`. According to [this](https://martinsosic.com/development/2016/02/08/wrapping-c-library-as-python-module.html) article it will make package installation faster and will not require user to have the same Cython version.)

It maybe worth mentioning - after building my package I get `.so` file for `mylib`. If I copy it to `mylib/` directory then from parent directory I can `import mylib` and access my methods using `mylib.mylib.say_hello()`. However it doesn't work on package installed from PyPI (on other PC) neither I don't want to use `mylib.mylib`.

If I should provide more info - let me know.

**Edit:**

My real project on GitHub: https://github.com/franiis/statr-python.

I want to successfully run `say_hello()` method from `statr.pyx` (other methods probably will not work).

I know code has some problems, but I want to first have a working core to fix and update everything. To build the project use `build_script.sh`. `upload_script.sh` creates a wheel and publishes it.

Comment: How do you install from PyPI? (download + `python setup.py install` or `pip install`). Any error message at that time? Any error (if so, exactly what are they) on `import mylib`? For Cython packages, you can either provide the pyx/pxd files or the c files, as you do. Both should work. For further info, please [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @PierredeBuyl Thank you for your interest. I tried `pip install <name>`. I got some usual error - pointing at first line of `__init__.py` and says `cannot install name 'mylib'`. At this point my whole project can be used as minimal example. I added link to github in question.

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues in the `setup.py`.

- The linked to library is not being compiled by `setup.py`. This means it must be compiled manually.
- The linked to library is a pre-compiled statically linked archive. This is *not portable* and cannot be distributed to anything other than the exact versions of GCC/glibc used to build it.
- The cython extension code is not being built by `setup.py`. Changes to .pyx/.pxd will not be reflected in the package.

Try something like:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize, build_ext

extensions = [Extension(
          name="statr._ext", 
          sources=["statr/_ext.pyx", "lib/mylib.c"],
          depends="lib/mylib.h",
          include_dirs=[numpy.get_include(), "lib/"]
]

setup(name='statr'
      packages=find_packages(),
      ext_modules=cythonize(extensions),
      build_ext: build_ext
      }
)
```

With the above, the name of the extension will be `statr._ext`. The name of the pyx should be `_ext.pyx`.

`mylib.c` will be built and linked to the extension by `setup.py`. Any additional compiler directives required by `mylib.c` should be added to the extension.

The package name will be `statr`. You should import anything from `_ext` that you want to be available from the top level `statrd` module in its `__init__.py`, for example

```
from ._ext import my_cython_function
```

Answer (score 1):

If the only thing to install in your project is a single extension module, there's no need to define any packages. You could simply install your extension as a top-level module:

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension
import numpy


setup(
    name = 'mylib',
    ...
    ext_modules = [
        Extension(
            name = 'mylib',
            sources = ['mylib/mylib.bycython.c'],
            include_dirs = [numpy.get_include(), 'lib/'],
            # cross-platform library names (without the "lib" prefix on Unix-likes):
            libraries = ['lib/mylib']
        )
    ],
    # legacy option for setup.py-style projects to install an unpacked distribution
    zip_safe = False,
    ...
)
```

and use it directly with `import mylib`.

Also note that in most cases there's no need to use `Cython` package in your `setup.py`. [`setuptools` does this for you](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/ext_modules.html#distributing-extensions-compiled-with-cython) and accepts the `.pyx` files as exten­sion sources.