# Is there a way to publish multiplatform wheels on PyPI with same version number?

Tags: raspberry-pi, cython, pypi, platform, python-wheel

I'm trying to deploy a Cython wrapped C++ module to PyPI as wheel. The goal is to make I2C hardware modules work with Python on any Raspberry Pi. So far I compiled the code and I know it works if I just copy compiled module from Pi 3B running Buster to Pi Zero W running Stretch, but when I deploy the wheel to test.pypi.org from Buster and try to install it on Stretch I get:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyiArduinoI2Crelay (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pyiArduinoI2Crelay
```

If I merely rename the wheel from *_armv7l.whl to *_armv6l.whl
module downloads and works on Pi Zero. But Pi 3B downloads previous version from PyPI (and i used *--no-cache-dir* and *rm -r .cache/pip/*)

If I do sdist and upload it complains about not having Cython installed upon installation of the module, although I know for a fact that it is installed, because it's the same Pi I compiled wheels before. (setup_requires and install_requires dont's seem to work)

So far none of these helped:

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0425/#platform-tag
https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#platform-wheels
https://wheel.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_guide.html#building-wheels
[Prepare C-based Cython package to publish on pypi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49471084/prepare-c-based-cython-package-to-publish-on-pypi)

Here's the link to the project:

https://github.com/tremaru/pyiArduinoI2Crelay

Here's the setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

def readme():
        with open('README.md') as readme:
                return readme.read()

setup(name='pyiArduinoI2Crelay',
        version='1.6.4.dev8',
        description='iarduino.ru module for Raspberry Pi',
        long_description=readme(),
        classifiers=[
                'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
        ],
        url='http://github.com/tremaru/pyiArduinoI2Crelay',
        author='iarduino.ru',
        author_email='shop@iarduino.ru',
        license='MIT',
        package=['pyiArduinoI2Crelay'],
        ext_modules = [Extension(
                name="pyiArduinoI2Crelay",
                sources=["pyiArduinoI2Crelay/pyiArduinoI2Crelay.cpp"])],
        include_package_data=True,
        python_requires='>=3',
        setup_requires=['Cython'],
        install_requires=['Cython'],
        cmdclass = {
                "build_ext": build_ext
        }
)
```

I want to be able to publish one version of the module for all Raspberries. So, is there a way to pack multiple .so's to one wheel? Or maybe some kind of manylinux1 tag for arm architecture?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I'm a knucklehead. I didn't need any Cython stuff in my setup after generating cpp file. All I needed to do is remove Cython stuff and remove `cmdclass = { "build_ext": build_ext }`. And then in publishes and builds as source distribution no problem.